# How to use python to extract a number by locating a specific word

Tags: python

I use python for programing, and i wonder how to extract a number by locating a specific word. For example, StoneA weights 10kg moves with speed 20m/s, StoneB weights 30kg moves with speed 40m/s. I know i can use re.findall to extract numbers. But if i just want to extract numbers relate with speed (which is 40 and 20). Is there a way to do it by locating the word "speed" or "m/s"

Comment: You will be needing regex for that. `re` document: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Why don't you regex for units like this `re.findall("(\d)(?:m/s|speed)", string)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> s = 'StoneA weights 10kg moves with speed 20m/s, StoneB weights 30kg moves with speed 40m/s'
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+)m/s', s)
['20', '40']
```

Regular expression `(\d+)m/s` captures one or more digits immediately followed by `m/s`.